# How do I get IntelliJ to recognize common Python modules?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 10 IDEA Ultimate Edition.

I've created a new file Test.py, and IntelliJ has correctly switched to Python parsing mode. (I can confirm this by typing "d", it pops up "def" as a suggestion, and hitting tab correctly gives me "def :")

However, when I try this code...

```
import os

cwd = os.getcw <Ctrl-space>
```

Two things happen....

1. I get a squggly underline underneath os and hovering over it gives me a "Unresolved reference 'os'" message
2. I get no suggestions hitting Ctrl-space above, when I'm expecting to see "getcwd".

I'm assuming that this must be a result of my not configuring IntelliJ properly in order to handle python modules, but I have no idea what it is I'm missing.

Any IntelliJ/Python users able to help me out?

Comment: I had the same issue, tried every answer on the internet. Turns out my 32 bit install of python was the issue. Uninstalled that and installed the latest 64 bit version and had no problems.

Comment: I had an issue where I would add a Python module in a monorepo, it would show as a module (bold text), but then when I closed the dialog it would disappear. The issue was the module was being automatically unloaded. So check `Load/Unload modules...` from Actions.

Answer (score 219):

Just create and add Python SDK

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK -> new
```

and select the installation path of your Python interpreter (for
example, `C:\Python26` in windows and `/usr/bin/python2.7` in Linux) as the home path.

Related discussion: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/286883

Comment: Still true today. OSX - /usr/bin/python

Comment: Today on OSX El Capitan I used this tip (thanks!); FWIW, the python interpreters (I had 2.6 and 2.7 installed) were in `/Library`, but IntelliJ found them just fine when I created a virtualenv.

Comment: Done that, no change.

Comment: For Mac with a homebrew-installed version of Python (advisable for El Capitan and beyond due to restrictions on system directories), you want `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to setup the facet (see answer below by @linuts)

Comment: also note that if you have an Anaconda distribution or similar, it's in `~/anaconda/bin/python` or `~/anaconda3/bin/python`

Answer (score 153):

Have you set up a python interpreter facet?

Open Project Structure <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

`Project settings -> Facets -> expand Python click on child -> Python Interpreter`

Then:

`Project settings -> Modules -> Expand module -> Python -> Dependencies -> select Python module SDK`

Comment: v12.1.4 Doesn't have the Project Settings > Facets menu option, but @db42's solution worked a treat

Comment: I have created a facet, and it did not work, your answer was the solution!! wonderfull! :)

Comment: Odd. I don't know what a facet is so I looked it up and the below page does not show python as an available facet.  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/available-facets-and-their-dependencies.html

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate has this feature, and it worked perfectly without breaking my Java module detection like db42's answer did.

Comment: after doing this it is not even showing suggestions to built in modules to which previously it was there

Comment: I had fixed mine by doing this step and then invalidating cache as per the answer below by @Alp

Comment: This is the correct answer. Notice that if your module has separate `_main` and `_test` sub-modules, then you will need to add the Python facet to those as well.

Comment: How do I include 2 python-versions in one project?

Comment: If the options show _No Interpreter_ then ensure Python is installed on your machine and configure in IntelliJ under the SDK option on the same open dialog - see [Configure system interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html)

Comment: Adding the interpreter to the facet was the solution for me

Answer (score 97):

If your Python SDK is properly configured and you are still facing the problem that builtins are not recognized, try this:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

Comment: After adding a virtual env back 5 times, this helped fix it for me with IDEA 2016.2.1

Comment: This was was fixed the problem for me after having added a virtual env.

Comment: I found that quitting and relaunching IntelliJ fixed it for me, I guess it's the same thing though

Comment: on 2021 this is still necessary, thank you! I was going nuts, everything was well configured :D

Comment: Yeah, old good Invalidate Caches did the trick..

Comment: After all these years...

Comment: This 7 year old solution still works for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 on Windows

Answer (score 19):

Here's what I had to do. (And I probably forgot an important aspect of my problem, which is that this wasn't set up as a Python project originally, but a Java project, with some python files in them.)

Project Settings -> Modules -> Plus button (add a module) -> Python

Then, click the "..." button next to Python Interpreter.

In the "Configure SDK" dialog that pops up, click the "+" button. Select "Python SDK", then select the default "Python" shortcut that appears in my finder dialog

Wait about 5 minutes. Read some productivity tips. :)

Click Ok

Wait for the system to rebuild some indexes.

Hooray! Code hinting is back for my modules!

Comment: This apparently solved my problems (also my project was initially created as a Java project)

Answer (score 7):

Few steps that helped me (some of them are mentioned above):

Open project structure by:

command + ; (mac users)
OR
right click on the project `->` Open Module Settings

1. Facets `->` + `->` Python `->` <your-project> `->` OK
2. Modules `->` Python `->` <select python interpreter>
3. Project `->` Project SDK `->` <select relevant SDK>
4. SDKs `->` <make sure it's the right one>

Click `OK`.

Open Run/Debug Configurations by:
Run `->` Edit Configurations

5. Python Interpreter `->` <make sure it's the right one>

Click `OK`.

Answer (score 6):

### Another possible fix (solved my problem)

You might have configured the environment properly but for some reason it broke along the way. In this case go to:

```
file > project settings > modules
```

Deploy the list of SDKs and look for a red line with `[invalid]` at the end.
If you find one, you have to recreate a python sdk.

It is likely that your previously working SDK is there too, but not red. Delete it.

Now you can click on the `new` button and add your favorite python virtualenv. And it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

(solved my problem)
File -> Project structures -> Modules -> Add (small plus sign) -> Import Module -> Add the path contains the files (e.g. src/mymodule) -> Create Module from existing sources -> Next -> next -> Finish.
You should see a file with .iml in the directory where you cannot import; that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved my problem (i have imported the project and it was showing there only, newly created files were not showing those errors):

1) Command + alt + R (Control in case of windows

2) Debug window will appear, select your file and press right arrow (->) and choose Edit then press enter (Edit configuration setting window will appear)

3) Under configuration, at the bottom you can see the error (please select a module with a valid python sdk), So in Python Interpreter, check Use Specified Interpreter, then in drop down you select your Python version

(In case python is not there download python plugin for intelliJ using following link  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html

4) Click on apply then close it.

Bingo it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work after I unchecked the following options in the Run/Debug Configurations for `main.py`

`Add content roots to PYTHONPATH`

`Add source roots to PYTHONPATH`

This is after I had invalidated the cache and restarted.

Answer (score 1):

resurrecting an old thread for 2022 - in my case I had to create a local python interpreter facet since i was using a remote one over SSH I'd get red squiggles even over `import time` even though it'd run on the remote system (A raspberry pi).

Some answers here work and say to make a facet but my case was different since i had one, just one that didn't work locally.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Requirements File](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-requirement-files.html?origin=old_help) (see link to JetBrains documentation)

In my case I needed `arrow`. So, I added

`arrow==0.7.0`

to my projects `requirements.txt`

Then Intellij prompted me to add the library the first time that I wrote `import arrow` in a Python script

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar to @Toddarooski 's, except that the module I had, under the "Dependencies" tab, had no SDK listed.  I right clicked on 'SDK', picked edit from the drop down menu, and selected my Python SDK.  That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Even my Intellisense in Pycharm was not working for modules like **time**
Problem in my system was no Interpreter was selected
Go to **File** --> **Settings...** (Ctrl+Alt+S)
Open **Project Interpreter**

[Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AMgX.png)
In my case  was selected. I selected the available python interpreter.
If not available you can add a new interpreter.