# IntelliJ IDEA Community with Python plugin does not recognize any Python modules

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I did a fresh Python 3.6.1 installation on a new Windows 10 machine, and loaded an old Python script into Intellij IDEA 2017 Community edition with Python plugin enabled. However, within IDEA *none* of the Python modules can be found, they all have that red underline. Even standard modules like `os` or `sys`.

I installed the modules that are really missing via `pip` but still, none is reconized in IDEA. Also, when I run Python from command line and for example `import os` there, that works fine.

Any ideas how I can let IDEA recognize the Python modules?

Comment: You should setup Python interpreter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6103029