# Intellij Idea: Python import showing error even when code using module is running

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-3.6

I am working on a python project using editor Intellij Idea, Ultimate 2017 Edition.

In my working file `sample.py` code looks like

```
import os

def sample_fuc():
    print(os.stat("C:\\Users\admin"))
```

Python SDK is already configured, code is running fine [When running through intellij run configuration] and printing the desired result, but somehow Intellij is not able to find the module `os` and showing error `No module named os`

So, I want to understand 2 things here :

1.) How does Intellij idea searches for modules available in python libraries. Do I need to configure somewhere in intellij to look for available modules. Is there something default set to it, if yes, why common module like os is not available in default path?

2.) If I need to configure, what all directory paths python usually have on windows where it stores installed modules?

Answer (score 0):

possible intellij is not able to identify your python interpreter path.

refer: [How do I get IntelliJ to recognize common Python modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102908/how-do-i-get-intellij-to-recognize-common-python-modules)

Comment: I believe python interpreter is already configured, that is how I am able to run the code through run configuration.